# jquery media queries changed css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, media-queries, responsive

I'm trying to find the mistake in my code for a while now but I can't figure out whats wrong. Any ideas?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        checkSize();
        $(window).resize(checkSize);
    });
    
    
    function checkSize(){
      if($(".testClass").css("float") == "none"){
          window.alert("Test");
      }
    }
```

```css
.testClass{
      float: left;
    }
    
    @media(max-width: 768px){
      .testClass{
        float: none;
      }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do

Comment: adding a media query to my js by watching if the css property is being changed.

Comment: media querys is to add styles based on the screen width or height

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
  console.log("Test1");
  checkSize();
  $(window).resize(checkSize);
});


function checkSize(){
  if($(".testClass").css("float") == "none"){
      console.log("Test");
  }
}

Comment: can you maybe describe what should happen

Comment: I know but i wanted to use this behavior for jquery to only execute my code if the css is being changed because there is an issue with the built in js ones

Comment: My javascript should execute if the screen-width is below 768px

Comment: ok, posted an answer, if you need anything else or different, please comment on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `$(window).width()` you can get the viewport width and do any validation width it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log('Window width: '+ $(window).width());
  checkSize();
});

function checkSize() {
  if($(window).width() < 768) {
    console.log("Run code...");
  }
}
```

```css
.testClass {
  float: left;
}

@media(max-width: 768px) {
  .testClass {
    float: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="testClass"></div>
```

Comment: @STAT1C I hope my answer solved your problem. If you havent accepted the answer, can you help me on why thats the case. Thank you